# Looking to color code census block groups by different categories in different columns in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm very new to QGIS and I am looking for the best way to color code census block groups by race. I have a CSV with columns for each race with the values in percents. What I'm looking to do is color code each block group as the race with the largest percent. For example, if a block group is %60 white, 20% Black and %20 Asian, that would be the color code for white.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. "Best" questions are often problematical here, since they have an inherent subjective quality to them.  "Is it possible?" questions could nearly always be answered with "Yes," so it really is best if you make an attempt and ask a specific question, since making an attempt is a basic expectation here.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: You can use categorized symbology based on an expression.